# Playing a GPX using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I keep a GPX file with timestamps for commercial flights, and I'm trying to create a system whereby I can take a GPX file (from my webserver), overlay it on a map and allow me to play it back in real time.  The idea is to make it like the moving maps you get on an aircraft, so I can overlay it onto videos I make.

Is there any way to do this with OpenLayers?  The GPX part isn't essential - I can get a KML or CSV of the same data, I'd just like to be able to play back in real time!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can parse GPX into OpenLayers and build a vector source, and of course a layer. Look at the OL examples, there is at least one that [reads a GPX](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/gpx.html?q=gpx):

```
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.2/examples/data/gpx/fells_loop.gpx',
    format: new ol.format.GPX()
  })
});
```

By default that would simply display the whole path. By using the timestamp information, you could then use the vector data and move an icon along the path

There are multiple examples available that show how to move an icon along a path:

- [Marker Animation example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html)
- [IGC Data example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/igc.html?q=cycle)